# Android: Multiple Insert INTO in one query not working on Php

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-volley

I need to send query from Android into Phpmyadmin. I sent too many queries like that. But first time I used Multiple insert into in the one query. And it doesnt work.

It's just for example.

```
String sqlcode = "INSERT INTO records (user_id,time) VALUES (2,NOW()); INSERT INTO recordimages (record_id,image,type) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),'"+imagename+"',0);";

params.put("sqlcode",sqlcode);
return params;
```

record_id is id of the records.

PHP

```
$sql= $_POST["sqlcode"];

require_once 'connect.php';
mysqli_query($conn,"SET NAMES 'utf8'");

$stmt = $conn->prepare("$sql");

$stmt->execute();
```

What did I try:

I tried same query in PHPmyadmin and it worked.  (I took the query from Log.e)

I removed last Insert INTO part and it worked. I removed LAST_INSERT_ID and it didn't work.

So the problem is in the second INSERT INTO. But I need last id after auto_increment.

Comment: `mysqli_query()` can only take one statement at the time. You need to use [mysqli_multi_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) to be able to execute multiple queries in one go.

Comment: _Side note:_ PHPMyAdmin is just a web based management tool for managing MySQL databases. You're application doesn't have any connection to PHPMyAdmin. It sends/inserts data into MySQL (which is the database).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i cant believe it's just easy like that. Thank you so much. I'm searching the problem for 1 hour. But i didn't select as an answer your comment. I think you need to add comment. And if you know how to i send multiple queries with stmt(prepared statements), you can add your answer :) I'm searching though. Thank you again.

Comment: As far as I know, you can only prepare one statement at the time. You need to send both queries and do one after the other. If you want to makes sure both works, you can always use transactions.